# Mongoose disconnecting after all save operations done

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm making save operations in loop. (I'm not collecting those promises, and not waiting for all saves to finish)
How do I disconnect from the db after all operations done?

I wanna do something like this:

[image]

Don't have enough memory to collect those promises

Comment: Collect those promises and wait for all saves to finish.

Comment: i don't want to collect those promises!

Comment: How else do you expect this to work?

Comment: How do you imagine to know when the operations are done, if you don't want to collect information on when they are done? I suppose you can use `setTimeout` with a 10 minute delay. Then you can be quite certain that 1: The save operations are done, and 2: You have written very inefficient code.

Comment: see edited question above

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why is it important for the project to not pick up the promises?

Comment: I'm doing scraping with big data. Collecting those promises will lead to memory leak

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.disconnect()` to close the connection to from mongoose. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-disconnect

Regarding tracking when operations are done - that's what the promises are for.

A simple way to ensure every item has been created, would be something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  name: Number,
});
const model = mongoose.model('test', schema);

async function run() {
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/test`);
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    await model.create({ name: i });
  }
  mongoose.disconnect();
}

run()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('completed exec');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during exec', err);
  })
```

This is not a great implementation, but it gets the job done. 
Things you should look into are:

1. could you batch requests? eg. use [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)
2. Errorhandling/continueability - what happens if one fails during the run? Should we stop or continue, but log the error?